# How can i set a global Background image in React-Native/Expo

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to set a global Background image in Expo for all Router-Paths. Since using the Css Background-Image Prop is not possible in Expo/React Native, I can not add it to the "Stack" Component.

I think I am taking the wrong approach -- What can I do?

Thx

What I tried:

- Using a Image below the "Stack/Navigation" Component and setting the zIndex lower than the Content zIndex.
- Surrounding the "Stack/Navigation" Component in the "ImageBackground" component.